# Trying to find a book about a military prison spaceship written in the 80's

Tags: story-identification, novel, spaceship, artificial-gravity

From what I remember, Humans were just starting space travel and got into a space war with a warrior race and got beaten badly. The warrior race were so disgusted with how poorly the humans fought they put the soldiers on a huge prison ship (to them this was the biggest insult).

The prison population was kept in a single, huge very tall room. Up and down the walls of the room there were small alcoves that would periodically dispense food, but not enough for all prisoners so they had to fight each-other off to get rations.

The gravity in the room varied so prisoners higher up could fly with some effort; but it got harder and harder the lower down the wall one went. Gravity on the floor was normal. The weaker a prisoner got the lower down the wall he would sink until he was stuck on the floor. There were no food dispensers on the floor level so all there was to eat was each other. The whole system was designed to humiliate the pitiful warriors and cause them to fight each other for food and to ultimately resort to cannibalism.

Comment: Could anyone provide a link or clue that would help me find this book? It needs to be in my library.

Comment: hey, just wanted to say I think the book you talked about looked so awesome that I ended up buying it :D So... thanks for asking about it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is it maybe [The last Deathship off Antares?](http://books.google.ro/books/about/The_Last_Deathship_Off_Antares.html?id=yt5YGwAACAAJ&redir_esc=y)
It was the answer to [this question](http://www.whatsthatbook.com/?xq=10375), which features a similar book:

> Human Fleet fought the Alien Fleet and lost. (The war has been long over
>   when the book begins) The human suvivors are put on prison ships in a
>   prison fleet and start a voyage to some alien destiation. [100s(?) ships
>   with 1000s(?) of prisoners on each] The ships are large cylinderical tubes
>   with the coffin like cells set in the walls. The cells have glass doors
>   that open and close on a set pattern (only 1 inmate per cell allowed, if 2
>   are in the door wont close. when the door closes there is food and water
>   and air and you can sleep.
>
> The alien guards never enter the cylinder, but they Do randomly play with
>   the cell controls, only powering some of them or only allowing food in some
>   of them. There are indicator lights so everyone knows which cells will be
>   working and which ones wont.
>
> This results in anarchy and daily battles as the prisoners fight to be in
>   "good" cells before the cells doors close. Once the cell doors close anyone
>   outside the cell will die. (not enough air)

Comment: That sure looks like it BBog, the title strikes a chord too. You did what many could not. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help, it was mostly luck! The book you wanted to find seemed awesome so I tried to search for it aswell